# Get name value of a powershell object property into a string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have imported a csv file

```
$infile = import-csv .\myfile.csv
```

Now I can show the columns (now object properties) by

```
$infile | gm -type NoteProperty

Name      MemberType

-------   ----------

Column1   NoteProperty

Column2   NoteProperty

etc...
```

What I want to do is get the value of the `Name(Column1..)` into a variable.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `select`

```
$infile | gm -type NoteProperty | select -ExpandProperty Name
```

e.g.,

```
$Names = @( $infile | gm -type NoteProperty | select -ExpandProperty Name )
```

Comment: $infile | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name   to avoid using aliases :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to go through `PSObject`:

```
$infile[0].PSObject.Properties |
  ? { $_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty' } |
  select -Expand Name
```

Using `$infile[0]` selects the first object from the collection, otherwise `.PSObject.Properties` would return the properties of the collection instead of the properties of a collection element.

Answer (score 0):

This should print `Column1`:

```
$infile = import-csv .\myfile.csv
$gm = $infile | gm -type NoteProperty
$name = $gm[0].Name
$name
```

Answer (score 0):

When importing cdv files using powershell, I normally specify a delimiter incase of more than a single value. Hope this helps all.

Example csv file

```
 Key     ValueA     ValueB
 ref1    valueA1    valueB1
 ref2    valueA2    valueB2
```

When opening a csv file using notepad

```
 Key;ValueA;ValueB
 ref1;valueA1;valueB1
 ref2;valueA2;valueB2
```

Using powershell to import that csv file into a variable

```
 $Hash = Import-Csv -path d:\test.csv -Delimiter ';'
```

Using powershell to query the csv file

```
 $Hash = Import-Csv -path d:\test.csv -Delimiter ';' |? {$_.ValueA -eq 'x' -and $_.ValueB -eq 'y'} | Select -exp Key
```